# Why class cast fails in run method even if checked instanceof, outside run

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following piece of code:

```
private void method(final Object obj){
  if (obj instanceof Processor){// assume Processor is some class
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ex.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            process((Processor) obj);//get ClassCastException here

        }
    });
}

private void process(final Processor a){
  //do something
}
```

My quesion is, even though I check if the obj is an instance of `Processor` class, and then only I cast it to `Processor` inside `run`() method, still I get `ClassCastException`  at the line where I'm invoking `process`() method, why?

Comment: can you show the complete piece of code that you use for casting'

Comment: The example you gave doesn't compile, so it can't be what you are actually running.

Comment: exactly, this is not valid Java

Comment: Did you rewrite this code? process(Processor obj) should be process((Processor) obj) and object should have to be final in order to be used in an inner class like that. Can we see the original code?

Comment: sorry guys, i cannot copy-paste code due to company policies, so rewrote the code. And yes, it is process((Processor) obj).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do, given `obj` is not final.

```
if (obj instanceof Processor) {
    final Processor processor = (Processor) obj; // use processor instead of obj.
```

Comment: obj is final, i have edited question to reflect that

Comment: @PratLee if you change the code the way I suggested, does it make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes cast exceptions happen between the same class when you have two class loaders loading the same class name from two different sources, and those sources are not identical. I see this problem sometimes when I invoke an EJB method between two applications that both load the "same" class from their own internal, packaged jar file. If those internal files don't align, this happens. Is there any chance you have the same class loaded from two different places?

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer is probably going to solve your problem.  But why not take this time to improve the overall design of your program.  Do you really want to pass **Object** into `method`(..)?  Why not:

```
interface Processable<I, O> { 
    O process(I input);
}
```

and have a `NoOp` Processor that simply does nothing.  What your doing right now is not very `OO`.